# How to use basic auth with username, password plus token in angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication

I have developed a form using Angular 4. In that form i have to send the form data using the post method using Angular 4. For that, i have tested with Postman and the data is coming properly. I have to use the Authorization type as Basic Auth with username and password.

And in the headers, i have to pass Content-Type as application/hal+json, Authorization as Basic  and X-CSRF-Token as  and lastly in the body i have to send some raw json data. Please have a look at the below screens shared.
[image]

[image]

[image]
So using Angular how to achieve this? Can anybody help mein this? I am struck at this point to achieve this.

The form which i have used is a dialog box:

```
<div class="container">
<app-dialog [(visible)]="showDialog">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div style="background-color:#363636; color:#ffffff; padding: 7px;
    margin: -12px -12px 12px -12px;">ADD NEW INVOICE</div>
    <div><label>Request ID *</label><input type="text"></div>
    <div><label>Date *</label>

      <my-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
      required></my-date-picker>

    </div>
    <div><label>Category *</label></div>
    <div><label>Details *</label></div>
    <div><label>Job (Optional)*</label></div>
    <div><label>Select Upload</label>
  <p>
    Single: <input type="checkbox" name="uploadtype" value="single" />
    Weekly: <input type="checkbox" checked name="uploadtype" value="weekly" />
    Monthly: <input type="checkbox" name="uploadtype" value="monthly" /><br />
  </p>
    </div>
    <div>Upload Document *: <span>
      <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">

    </span></div>
    <div>Amount *</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </app-dialog>
</div>
```

So my question is how do i send the form data to server.

The service i have created is:

```
private headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    getInvoiceDetails(){
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
            return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + 'api/supplier-invoice/121', { headers: headers })
            .map(response => response.json());
        }
```

I am very much puzzled about this as i am very novice user to this Angular and authentication concept. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use Post request if you want send data in body. In the code you are using get request

Answer (score 0):

Use Post request if you want send data in body and I am also seeing the postman screen shot as post requestion but in the code you are using get request. PFB the sample code for post request

```
registerUser(registration: RegistrationTO): Promise<String> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let body = JSON.stringify(
      {
        "userName": registration.userId,
        "emailId": registration.emailId,
        "userId": registration.userId
      }
    );
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let requestOption: RequestOptionsArgs =
      {search: params,  headers: headers };
    return this.http
      .post(RegistrationUrl, body, requestOption)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch((err)=>{
        this.handleError(err);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public login(event):
Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
var username = event.target.elements[0].value;
var password = event.target.elements[1].value;
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Authorization', "Basic "+btoa(username+':'+password));

console.log(headers);

return this.http.get<Config>(
  "http://localhost:8081/users/login",  {
    headers, observe: 'response',
    withCredentials: true
  });
```

}

**withCredentials: true is enough to handle the cookie**